# How to evaluate array formulae with the Evaluate method

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, excel-formula

In VBA, the `Evaluate()` and `[]` methods can both be used to return arrays:

```
Dim i As Variant
i = Evaluate("{1,2;3,4}")
i = [{1,2;3,4}]
```

both lines set `i` to be a 2D array containing the numbers 1-4. An added functionality is that `Evaluate(...)(1,2)` returns the R1C2 indexed element of the array (i.e. 2 - `[...](1,2)` meanwhile errors)

I'm wondering whether there's any syntax for evaluating an array-returning worksheet function in the same way, e.g.

```
i = Evaluate("LEN(A1:A5)>3") 'or similar like [{LEN(A1:A5)>3}]
```

which should return the 1D array like `{False,False,False,True,True}` if I have text longer than 3 characters in `A4` & `A5`, but it doesn't.

If not, is there another 1-liner way of evaluating an array-formula to return the full array? I'm looking for whatever approach gives the smallest character-count.

Comment: `i = Evaluate("ROW(A1:A5)>3")`

Comment: @SJR, bizarre that that works, but `i = Evaluate("LEN(A1:A5)>2")` does not. I would expect that to return an array but it only returns a single boolean, is there some ambiguity I'm overlooking?

Comment: Bizarre indeed. I'm not sure why, but some functions need to be "forced" to work in the correct way, e.g. this works `i = Evaluate("IF(ROW(A1:A5),LEN(A1:A5)>2)")`

Comment: @SJR Hmm, that seems buggy, maybe it's a conflict with VBA builtins because I notice `Evaluate(ISERROR(A1:A5))` also doesn't work as expected.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Some not-array-functions are putting itself in array context when their parameters are arrays. Those functions can easily be used in array context in `SUMPRODUCT`. But some functions need to be forced into array context using [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter]. Those functions can **not** easily be used in array context in `SUMPRODUCT`. Unfortunately there are not lists of which functions are the one or the other as far as I know.

Comment: @SJR As I say, I'm trying to find the *lowest character count* method for evaluating worksheet functions to return an array. I was aware that the `Evaluate` method *could* return an array, so I wanted to know under what circumstances/ with what syntax. The question is specifically about how to use that method to return an array, as I couldn't easily find anything else on the subject. Of course a work-around (looping over the range) would be an acceptable answer, but I don't think it can be showed that that will be lower character count until the details of _this_ method are fully established.

Comment: Yes but to what end? I'm not sure it is possible to "fully establish" the details of this method, e.g. see @AxelRichter's response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To return an array, you need to use a function that supports an array as a result.

The function usually used with VBA to evaluate an expression to an array is [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) since it doesn't alter the values :

```
Dim data()
data = Evaluate("INDEX(LEN(A1:A5)>3,)")
```

Comment: Its fun that depending on the input, it gives one or two dimensional array. E.g. `A1:A5` is with 2 dimensions, `A1:G1` is with one.

Comment: `A1:A5` is a column vector while `A1:G1` is a row vector. So the surprise about different array results should be not so big.